# Keyboard hides the input field in the footer when the keyboard is visible

Tags: ionic-framework

In my ionic Project,In chatting page i have included one input box at the footer section,But when the keyboard is open for typing the input box in invisible.

[image] [image]

**chat.html**

```
<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-grid>
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-10>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" [(ngModel)]="message" name="message"></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2 (click)="sendMessage()">
      <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it Ionic [Keyboard Plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/)

in terminal:

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard

npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

add in: `app.module.ts`

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

providers: [
    ...
    Keyboard
    ...
  ]
```

in: `chart.html`

```
   <ion-footer>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-10>
              <ion-input type="text" (focus)="showKeyboard()" 
                (focusout)="closeKeyboard()" placeholder="Type a message" 
                [(ngModel)]="message" name="message"></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-2 (click)="sendMessage()">
               <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
       </ion-grid>
     </ion-toolbar>
   </ion-footer>
```

in: `chart.ts`

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

   showKeyboard() {
      this.keyboard.show();
    }

   closeKeyboard() {
       this.keyboard.close();
    }
```

Comment: Still the input field is invisible

Comment: Test it on device

Comment: tested in emulator